# Accessing same piece of code from two classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have two classes each with an instance method that use the same piece of code.

This piece of code takes a NSString and return an NSArray.

Currently the same piece of code is repeated in the two classes.

Is there a way to write it separately and call it by the two classes? I tried to make a method in a subclass of NSArray, but there are many problems due to the fact that NSArray is an abstract class. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a NSString category. This category will return the array.
E.g.:

```
//
//  NSString+MyCategory.h

#import 

@interface NSString (MyCategory)

-(NSArray *)myMethod;

@end

//
//  NSString+MyCategory.m

#import "NSString+MyCategory.h"

@implementation NSString (MyCategory)

-(NSArray *)myMethod {
    NSArray *_arr = [self componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    return _arr;
}

@end
```

Then in your class (or whatever you want in your code) you can import the category:

```
#import "NSString+MyCategory.h"
```

and then use it on any string:

```
NSArray *myArray = [anyString myMethod];
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of subclassing NSArray, the correct approach to extent the behaviour of a class is to create a category on that class.

So, you can create a category on NSString that returns an array, and after you have imported that category to your project, you can call it as if it was part of NSString, for example:

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello";
NSArray *myArray = [myString generateArrayFromString];
```

You can find a guide on how to create a category here:

[Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Comment: Don't use `get` in method names like this, it has a more specific meaning in the context of Cocoa. If you name a method `get` it usually implies that the caller is responsible for providing the buffer to *get* the output. For examples, see `getObjects:range:` from `NSArray` and `getCharacters:range:` from `NSString`, and `getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:` from `NSStream`.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it (parsing a string into an NSArray, with on reference to the class's instance fields) you can make the method a class (vs instance) method and invoke it from either class.

Ie:

```
+(NSArray*)parseThisString:(NSString*)theString {
    doSomething;
    return result;
}
```

Invoke with `[TheNameOfTheClass parseThisString:inputString]`.

Of course, if you are reverencing values in the class's instance this won't work.